# How to change global scope for a method call in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to call a method from another iframe:

```
window.parent.frames[1].processInnerMessage(outerMessage)
```

but I want it to have scope of `window.parent.frames[1]` and not my current `window` so that it would process the `outerMessage` as if it was originated inside that `frame[1]` locally.

- is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: `processInnerMessage` already *is* called with `frames[1]` as its `this` context. Not sure what your problem is?

Comment: @Bergi I want to change `global` context, not `this`, so that all the calls inside `processInnerMessage` like `document.getElementById()` would be called with `frames[1].document` context, not my current `window.document.`

Comment: You cannot change that. You will have to define the function in the correct scope in the first place. Where and how is it created?

Answer (score 0):

`window.parent.frames[1].processInnerMessage` already gets called with the scope of `window.parent.frames[1]`, no matter where or how you are calling it. The function's lexical scope is created when the function is and can't be changed after that.

If by any chance the question would actually be whether you can share functions between iframes so that the functions will actually get the same context as the *caller* instead of the *callee*, then this would be a bit more interesting.

That is, if we have a container html

```
<iframe src="frame0.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="frame1.html"></iframe>
```

frame1.html then defines a global function like

```
function processInnerMessage(outerMessage){
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = outerMessage;
}
```

and now frame0.html would like to print out its message

```
window.parent.frames[1].processInnerMessage('Hi there, neighbour!');
```

As explained above, this will result in the message being printed to the element  in frame1.html. But perhaps frame0.html has element with id 'message' too and we'd like to print the message there.

### Option 1: Define the function separately in both frames

Just load the script that contains this processInnerMessage function separately in both iframes so you can call `processInnerMessage()` without any `frames[1]` stuff. This is the obvious and honestly the best solution, there is very little reason to use any other tricks.

### Option 2: Don't rely on global scope

Instead of writing `document.getElementById('message')` you could write something like `(this||window).document.getElementById('message')` and then expect the caller to change the value of `this` with `.processInnerMessage.call(window, 'Hi there, neighbour!')`

### Option 3: The evil one

This is the hackiest solution of these and I wouldn't recommend using it, but it is also the only solution here to answer the actual question "is that [changing the scope] possible?". It is, by essentially re-creating the function with eval.
In frame0:

```
var processInnerMessage;
eval('processInnerMessage=' + window.parent.frames[1].processInnerMessage);
processInnerMessage('Hi there neighbour!');
```

Ugly and will break if you use any other functions in `processInnerMessage` that you haven't defined in frame0, but at least the message gets printed in the right frame.